# One NLB or many NLB per VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Network Load Balancers do cost a bit of money. And as far as functionality goes it looks like I only really need 1 NLB per a VPC if I have services running in a private Subnet and I need a NLB to make a VPC connection, such as between API Gateway and my VPC. But when I was setting up all my services I created a LoadBalancer per service, and now there are 3 services across a couple of environments and it seems like it is costing a bit of money now, and I am thinking of getting rid of them and using one load balancer rather per VPC.

What are best practices in this area? Should you try and reduce the number of load balancers you have in your account to save $$$.

Comment: do you own all the VPCs? if yes, why not use VPC peering.

Comment: The question is should I use 1 NLB for many services, or one for each to save money. I don't need to connect VPCs.